# Print the input one word per line

Tags: c

right now I am writing a program on C language based on the task 1.12 from Brian and Ritchie book. The program has to output the input stream one word per line. Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
int ct;
while((ct = getchar()) != EOF){
    if(ct == ' '){
        ct = ct - ' ';
        putchar(ct);
        printf("\n");
    }else if(ct == '\n'){
        ct = ct - '\n';
        putchar(ct);
        printf("\n");
    }
  }
}
```

It seems to work, but it only outputs blank lines when I enter the input. Where did I mess up?

Comment: what is you input,output and expected output?

Comment: What if its *neither* newline nor space ? look at your code and ask yourself what happens *then* ? And fyi, `ct = ct - ' '` has a pungent code smell. You just determined that `ct` was a space, so that equation guarantees `ct` will be zero (0), and you're thus shoving a nullchar terminator into stdout. Same goes for your treatment of newline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, you have the two cases where you check if `ct` is either a space (`' '`) or a newline character (`'\n'`), and these are the only places where you are printing out the character, using `putchar`. Your code isn't ever printing anything out outside of these two cases, so you need to add a case to handle regular characters and to print those out as well. Something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
int ct;
while((ct = getchar()) != EOF){
    if(ct == ' '){
        ct = ct - ' ';
        putchar(ct);
        printf("\n");
    }else if(ct == '\n'){
        ct = ct - '\n';
        putchar(ct);
        printf("\n");
    } else {
        putchar(ct)
  }
}
```

Also, while `putchar` does take an `int` as an argument, you do not need to manually convert it using `ct - ' '`, for example. You can pass the `ct` `char` directly to `putchar` and it will print it out accordingly

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will accept your answer when stackoverflow allows to.